# how to fix $(this) inside another $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

u gave a problem in this code it gives me $(this).fadeIn() is not a function, any thoughts ?

```
$('img').hide().each(function(){
        $(this).load(function(){
            $(this).fadeIn();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you meant fixing the outer $(this) in inner function, you can do:

```
$('img').hide().each(function(){
        var outer = $(this);
        outer.load(function(){
            outer.fadeIn();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Nice answer... small nitpick (and since this is sample code, it doesn't apply to this example): it's a good idea to give references to `$(this)` a useful name as opposed to `outer`... something like `image_reference` would be more useful.

Comment: The most common convention I've seen is to use `that`, which also makes clear your intent.

Comment: Agree with you guys - definitively necessary to use meaningful names in real projects/situations. I used `outer` on purpose above to make it abstract - you have outer context starting on the first and inner starting on the 4th line of my example.

Comment: Thanks a lot .... Fast and Genius !! ... it's doesn't matter which $(this) is fixed as long "this" is fixed ... hahaha

Answer (score 3):

The value of `this` changes inside of nested functions — its value isn't "captured" the way other variables are.

To avoid this, you can assign `this` to another variable!

```
$('img').hide().each(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    that.load(function(){
        that.fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Not sure what the issue would be. In the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event handler, `this` references the element that received the event, so there should be no reason to close around the outer `this`.

If you're not doing anything else in the `.each()`, you could get rid of that:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/b4cNZ/1/

```
$('img').hide().load(function() {
   $(this).fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Otherwise, if you needed to test to make sure the image gets revealed when cached, you could do this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/b4cNZ/2/

```
$('img').hide().each(function() {
    if (this.complete) {
        $(this).fadeIn(2000);
    } else {
        $(this).load(function() {
            $(this).fadeIn(2000);
        });
    }
});
```